# Why I couldn't insert elements into the list with contiguous implementation in C?

Tags: c, list, data-structures, contiguous

I did implement a list in C as follows. The problem is when I try to insert elements using `InsertList()` function it returns "**Try to insert to a position not in list**" message. But instead I wanted the list to insert the elements in the said positions. To make it happen how I should modify my code?.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20
#define EMPTY 0
#define FULL MAX-1

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} Boolean;
typedef char ListEntry;
typedef int Position;
typedef struct list
{
    int count;
    ListEntry entry[MAX];
}List;

void CreateList(List *l)
{
    l->count=EMPTY;
}

Boolean IsListEmpty(List *l)
{
    return (l->count==EMPTY);
}

Boolean IsListFull(List *l)
{
    return (l->count==FULL);
}

int ListSize(List *l)
{
    return (l->count);
}

void InsertLast(ListEntry x,List *l)
{
    if(IsListFull(l))
        printf("Try to insert to full list\n");
    else
    {
        l->entry[l->count]=x;
        l->count++;
        printf("The entered element at last is %d\n", x);
    }
}

void InsertList(Position p,ListEntry x,List *l)
{
    if(IsListFull(l))
        printf("Try to insert to full list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to insert to a position not in list\n");
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i=ListSize(l)-1;i>=p;i--)
            l->entry[i+1]=l->entry[i];
        l->entry[p-1]=x;
        printf("The entered element is: %d\n",x);
        l->count++;
    }
}

void ReplaceList(Position p,ListEntry x,List *l)
{
    if(IsListFull(l))
        printf("Try to replace to full list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to replace a position not in list\n");
    else
        l->entry[p-1]=x;
}

void DeleteList(Position p,List *l)
{
    int i;
    if(IsListEmpty(l))
        printf("Try to delete from a empty list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to delete a position not in list\n");
    else
    {
        ListEntry x=l->entry[p-1];
        for(i=p-1;i<ListSize(l);i++)
            l->entry[i]=l->entry[i+1];
        l->count--;
        printf("Deleted element is %d\n", x);
    }
}

void RetrieveList(Position p,List *l)
{
    if(IsListEmpty(l))
        printf("Try to retrieve from a empty list\n");
    else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))
        printf("Try to retrieve a position not in list\n");
    else{
        ListEntry x=l->entry[p-1];
    printf("Retrieved element is: %d\n", x);
    }
}
void Traverse(List *l)
{
    if(IsListEmpty(l))
        printf("Try to traverse a empty list\n");
    else
        printf("The elements of this list are: ");
    {
        for(int i=0;i<ListSize(l);i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", l->entry[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My `main()` function is as follows:

```
{
    List l;
    CreateList(&l);
    Traverse(&l);
    DeleteList(2,&l);
    //InsertLast(5,&l);
    //InsertLast(6,&l);
    InsertList(1,3,&l);
    InsertList(2,2,&l);
    InsertList(3,1,&l);
    RetrieveList(1,&l);
    DeleteList(2,&l);
    int results = ListSize(&l);
    printf("The size of the list%d\n",results);
    Traverse(&l);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you call `InsertList(1,3,&l);`, `p` is 1 and therefore the test `(p<0 || p>ListSize(l) is true (because initially the list size is 0)

Comment: Try inserting at position 0, InsertList(0, 1, &l);

Comment: regarding: `printf("Try to insert to full list\n");`  the function: `printf()` needs its' prototype, so the code is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: regarding: `}````  This causes the code to not compile!  Suggest removing those trailing back ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning. Your list is empty. So, `ListSize` returns 0. You tries to insert to the position 1 which is definitely outside of the list boundaries. Try to insert at position 0. It makes sense as the list is empty, position 0 is not set. Why to insert at position 1?

There is some more bugs in your code. For example, when you insert, you want to shift the content first and then set the new element. You set it at index `(p-1)`. Following your logic by inserting at position 1 it may work but it is confusing. If you insert something at certain position, it should be inserted exactly there.

Your code may look like this

```
 void InsertList(Position p,ListEntry x,List *l)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     if(IsListFull(l))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         printf("Try to insert to full list\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
         printf("Try to insert to a position not in list\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         int i;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
         for(i=ListSize(l)-1;i>=p;i--)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
             l->entry[i+1]=l->entry[i];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         l->entry[p]=x;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         printf("The entered element is: %d\n",x);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
         l->count++;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

I saw that you have an extra function `InsertLast` but the `InsertList` can also successfully append an element. It is up to you to leave it as is or forbid appending in the insert function.

So, happy debugging!

Comment: Thank you @rhaport for the help.

Answer (score 0):

On first insert count of elements in list is 0, so ListSize() will return 0.
Consequently, condition 'if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l))' can not be satisfied.

```
void InsertList(Position p,ListEntry x,List *l)
    {
        if(IsListFull(l))
            printf("Try to insert to full list\n");
        else if(p<0 || p>ListSize(l)) // the condition is never satisfied
     ...
```

Instead, try with condition if(p<0 || p>= MAX).
Further, you have additional mistakes in your InsertList function. Try to write something similar to following code:

```
else if(p<0 || p>= MAX)
    printf("Try to insert to a position not in list\n");
else
{
    int i;
    for(i=MAX-2;i>=p;i--)  // important point
        l->entry[i+1]=l->entry[i];
    l->entry[p-1]=x;
    printf("The entered element is: %d\n",x);
    l->count++;
}
```